# jQuery AJAX call not working, no idea why

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've had a couple of people look at this and we simply can't figure out why it isn't working. It's simply intercepting a form submit, serializing the data and then returning the results.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#changepassword').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php?action=changepassword",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $("#changepassword").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
                if(data == "password_changed"){
                    alert("Password Changed");
                }else{
                    alert("Password not changed, please try again.");
                }
            }
        });
    })
})
```

Even if I send the url to test.php and just write `asd` on there, it won't return anything.

The submit itself is working, and I'm even getting a return when I look at the network preview. The status is 200 (OK) and everything is fine, it just simply isn't reaching the success: part.

Note: I have tried using `.done()` instead and I get the exact same problem.

I am using bootstrap, if maybe their javascript file could be causing an issue, but I doubt it.

Thanks.

Comment: `;` semicolons dude.

Comment: That's not the issue, lol, everything is working up until success.

Comment: @ChrisEvans see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line `dataType: "json"`, unless you're expecting a json object as response from server. `dataType` is the type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

[Here's the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Your jQuery should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#changepassword').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php?action=changepassword",
            type: "post",
            data: $("#changepassword").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
                if(data == "password_changed"){
                    alert("Password Changed");
                }else{
                    alert("Password not changed, please try again.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I knew it'd be something that's staring me in the face, thank you, this worked :)